# How to customize cellForRowAtIndexPath TableView method to display data from different sources depending on action taken?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I basically have two arrays, which I'd like to display in a TableView one at a time:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *items;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *historicItems;
```

that is either `items` or  `historicItems` shall be shown in the TableView depending on the action taken.

What is the proper way to choose the array to be displayed? Cells to be displayed in the TableView are prepared in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath` method.

Comment: Nope. I mean there are two arrays in the data source. I would like the table view to display either one or the other array.

Comment: It would be interesting to know why my question got downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `BOOL` in your class and make it true or false in your actions,

```
//define in your .h or wherever you want to declare

BOOL flag;
```

and than either make it true or false in your actions. than in `CellForRowAtIndexPath` do like that to select the datasource based on your action.

```
If (flag){
cell.textLabel.text=[items objectAtIndex:IndexPath.row];
}
else{
cell.textLabel.text=[historicalItems objectAtIndexPath.row];
}
```

and also you have to return count of cell from these two data source as well in `numberofcell` function by using the same if else statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can add bool variable and change it depends on the action taken. In your table view datasource methods do stuff depending on the bool variable, for example:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (action == YES) //your first action 
        return items.count;
    else //second action
        return historicItems.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Your code to init cell here
    .......
    if (action == YES) //your first action 
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = items[indexPath.row];
    }
    else //second action
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = historicItems[indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way:

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if (showItems)
        {
            return items.count;
        }
        else
        {
            return historicItems.count;
        }
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
             cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
        if (showItems)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [historicItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

depending on the action you can choose to reload the tableview with the required items. use any boolean variable to keep track of which action is selected.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger count;
    if (isItems == YES) //your first action 
        count = items.count;
    else {
         count = historicItems.count;
    }

    return count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (isItems == YES)  
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = items[indexPath.row];
    }
    else 
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = historicItems[indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1st way**
If both of array's contains are same then take datasourcearray. Then `copy` your appropriate  array data into datasourcearray on button action.

```
datasourcearray = [self.items copy];
[yourtable reloadData];
```

similar action for onther array.

**2nd way**
If both array contain is different then take one Boolean value (suppose `isFirstSenarioFlag`)
toggle value YES or NO on button pressed. Check your flag value in each datasource and delegate method and load appropriate data of table after reloading data method.

In first way you need not take care of set flag value aur checking datasource in every table datasource and delegate method. Also it will reduce run time complexity (toggling each and every method) of program and easy to manage memory too. :)